# Data format for generating table with json mvc ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm doing some queries in the database and must return through the Json, but I can not hit the fomato. I'm doing the following:

```
var dataResult = new List<List<Object>>();
```

I query the database and and add below

```
dataResult.Add(new List<object>(new object[] { "rRod:" + rod, "rKmI:" + vlrkmI, "rKmF:" + vlrkmF, "rExt:" + ext, "rSol:" + sol }));
```

To assemble the table use

```
function (data) {
    $("#divResult").empty();

    //Adicionar a tabela na div
    table = "<fieldset style='height:50px '><legend>Resultado da Matriz</legend><table id='tableResult'><tr><th>Rod</th>";
    table += "<th>kmI</th><th>kmF</th><th>Ext</th><th>Sol</th></fieldset>"
    $("#divResult").append(table);

    $(eval(data)).each(function (data) {
    $("#tableResult").append(
        "<tr><td>" + this.rRod+ "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + this.rKmI + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + this.rKmF + "</td>"
        "<td>" + this.rExt + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + this.rSol + "</td></tr>");
});
```

But not this genrando the table with values​​.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you are doing. Could you read this and try again? http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: What I'm wondering is how should be the format of the json output to generate a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest you to do is instead of doing a list of object create a class with those properties something like this :

```
var dataResult = new List<List<sometypewhichhasallofthosejsobproperties>>();
```

Now from the mvc action just simply return jsonresult of the dataresult. This should format your data to json nicely and you should be able to work with it in jquery easily.